# Tagged template literals confusion

Tags: javascript, html, string, ecmascript-6, interpolation

I'm at the point in my learning curve of JavaScript where I need to learn some more complex things to get better, and I'm starting with tagged template literals but I can't seem to wrap my head around how they work. I've watched tutorials, looked on GitHub and a slew of sites offering help and I still have no idea what they're talking about. I want to append the `testParse` and `studyParse` variables into my HTML using the `parseHTML` function. I've tried using `createElement` but it felt like a copout, because if I was creating a `div` element like that I'd be missing the point of tagged template literals. I'm using this in a project so that is why I have some weird strings. Please **thoroughly** explain how the function you write works and what it's doing so I gain full understanding.

```
const testInf = `Test your skills`;
const studyInf = `Study with flashcards`;
let testParse = parseHTML `<div>${testInf}</div>`;
let studyParse = parseHTML `<div>${studyInf}</div>`;

function parseHTML(){

};

console.log(parseHTML);
```

Comment: I don't understand your question, what does DOM manipulation has to do with template literals?

Comment: What do you mean you tried using `createElement`? Can you show that attempt?

Comment: @ – Ry-♦ I never said I want the easy way. And even so I don't know how to add them to the DOM. To have to use `innerHTML` I would need some HTML already there, but I want to create the HTML with js and append it to the DOM.

Comment: @– Ry-♦ By attempt I really mean that I set it up and then erased it because it misses what I want to achieve. I want to add the `textParse` and the `studyParse` to the DOM as html through the `parseHTML` function

Comment: You're asking "_how the function works_" but the function body in the example is empty ..? What comes to the task itself, creating HTML from strings, whether they're "tagged literals" or not, is not recommended.

Comment: @Teemu I edited the question feel free to read it over again.

Comment: Umh ... there's nothing hard in this. If you've a running script on a page, you're also having HTML elements, like `body`, which you can use to add new elements in many different ways.

Comment: @Teemu I think you're missing the point. I'm trying to learn about tagged template literals, more precisely using them to append HTML to the DOM. That might not be how I use them in the project but I want to understand them at least.

Comment: "_Tagged template literal_" is just a string. `\`<div>${studyInf}</div>\`` is exactly the same as `"<div>" + studyInf + "</div>"` ...

Comment: @Teemu And how would I add that to the DOM through a function

Comment: You've mentioned several different ways to do it in your question and comments already. `innerHTML`, `outerHTML`, `insertAdjacentHTML` ...

Comment: @Teemu but I thought those were all only useful if the element was already in the DOM. Can you please explain how I could add it to the dom with those I never knew you could do that.

Comment: There's always `body` element in the DOM, that's the element you start from. Like I said from the beginning, this is something you shouldn't even do with simple vanilla JS, in jQuery there is a lot of safety checking when creating HTML from strings, and explaining all that would make an answer far too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add those strings into your HTML using `parseHTML`, just use `innerHTML`:

```js
const testInf = `Test your skills`;
const studyInf = `Study with flashcards`;
let testParse = `<div>${testInf}</div>`;
let studyParse = `<div>${studyInf}</div>`;

function parseHTML() {
  document.body.innerHTML += `${testParse}<br>${studyParse}`;
};

parseHTML();
```

Comment: Well I feel stupid when I see `innerHTML` in there. I never even thought of adding it to the DOM through body, I forgot `innerHTML` changes more than text.

Comment: No problem whatsoever @TheNuthouse, always glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates):

> A more advanced form of template literals are **tagged templates**. **Tags allow you to parse template literals with a function**. The first argument of a tag function contains an array of string values. The remaining arguments are related to the expressions. In the end, your function can return your manipulated string (or it can return something completely different as described in the next example). The name of the function used for the tag can be whatever you want.

So, basically you can use the `tag` as a **function** to **parse** the `template literal`. In your particular case, you have to define the arguments of the parser function that tags the template literal to do something:

```js
const testInf = `Test your skills`;
const studyInf = `Study with flashcards`;
let testParse = parseHTML `<div>${testInf}</div>`;
let studyParse = parseHTML `<div>${studyInf}</div>`;

function parseHTML(arrayOfStrings, exp1)
{
    // We will just return a string with the received arguments.
    return JSON.stringify(arrayOfStrings) + exp1;
};

console.log(testParse);
console.log(studyParse);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

So as you can see, the variables `testParse` and `studyParse` will hold whatever the parser function (parseHTML) returns. Now, that we learn how they work, lets see an example related to what you want to do (i.e add HTML content).

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    console.log(putOption `Item${i}`);
}

function putOption(strings, exp1)
{
    let newli = `<li>${strings[0]} ${exp1 + 1}</li>`;
    document.getElementById("ul").innerHTML += newli;
    return `Element ${newli} was added!`;
};
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:30% !important;}
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
```

```html
<ul id="ul"></ul>
```

However, you can basically approach the same without using they.